# How to export a variable that takes its value from an async function

Tags: javascript, export, es6-modules

I apologize if my question sounds stupid, but I found that I need in many situations global variables such as ones that represent database and redis clients to be used in many files, however these variables themselves need to wait to get their values from promises or async functions that initialize the communication to the database or redis servers.

I want to do something like that

**init.js:**

```
export default async () => {
   return await initializeWhatever()
}
```

**db.js:**

```
import init from './init'
let db = null
init().then(val => db = val)
export default db
```

**api.js:**

```
import db from './db'
const doApi = req => {
 db('users').select({username:req.param.username})
}
```

However the `db` variable imported in `api.js` is always null, why doesn't it get updated to the correct value when `init()` finishes? If my approach to using db is wrong, what is the correct way to export global variables that are computed asynchronously?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you export a variable, you're exporting what's stored in the variable, not the variable itself. Assigning to the variable will only change the variable, but will not affect what was exported.

Think of it like this:

```
let a = null;
let b = a;
a = 'something';
console.log(b);
// null
```

Note how storing something new in `a` doesn't change what's stored in `b`.

To do something like what you want in your question,  you need to export an object and update references on that object:

**init.js**

```
export default async () => {
    return await initializeWhatever()
}
```

**db-module.js**

```
import init from './init'
const dbModule = { db: null };
init().then(val => dbModule.db = val)
export default dbModule
```

**api.js**

```
import dbModule from './db-module'
const doApi = req => {
    dbModule.db.select({username:req.param.username})
}
```

Obviously you might want to change some names to make things cleaner. I don't know a lot about your project so I'm not sure how to name them.

Also, you'll have to make sure have some way of making sure that any uses of your `dbModule.db` object happen *after* it's actually in place. In other words, you have to make sure there's no way `doApi` in `api.js` can be invoked before `init` in `db-module.js` finishes.

To do this, you'll need to make the promise chain from `init` available to `api.js`:

**init.js**

```
export default async () => {
    return await initializeWhatever()
}
```

**db-module.js**

```
import init from './init'
const dbModule = { db: null };
dbModule.promise = init().then(val => dbModule.db = val)
export default dbModule
```

**api.js**

```
import dbModule from './db-module'
const doApi = req => {
    dbModule.db.select({username:req.param.username})
}
dbModule.promise.then(() => {
    // Set up routes and start listening in this promise chain.
    // Ensure there is no way `doApi` can be called before this happens.
});
```

Why does this work? Because in JS, variables don't store entire copies of objects. They simply store [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference). If two variables point at the same object, changes to the object will be reflected whether your access it through one variable or another. Think of it like this:

```
let c = { prop: null };
let d = c;
c.prop = 'something';
console.log(d.prop);
// 'something'
```

Comment: It now works, thanks! however I afraid I still don't fully understand what the first statement of your answer really means, and why your example worked while mine didn't since we both changed the exported variable one way or another, you just update a property, is there any articles or doc that elaborates on this matter?

Comment: It's a simple matter of understanding references in JS. When you import something, you're creating a new variable that references *the exported value*. It does not bind it to a variable that may happen to be referencing that same value at the time of the export. If the exported value was `null`, then the variable created by the import will always be `null`. You may find this question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: I realized my comments could be better done as edits. So edits have been made. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a getter. Something about

```
export default function getDB() {
  return db;
}
```